# ¿Se puede bloquear una clase que se encuentra en un servidor GIT con VisualStudio?

Tags: visual-studio, git

Tengo esta solución que posee un proyecto Android (Xamarin) y está en un repositorio de **Bonobo GIT Server.**

[image: Img muestra]

Lo que yo quisiera saber es si hay alguna posibilidad de **bloquear** la clase `MainActivity.cs` para que nadie más que trabaje sobre el mismo proyecto pueda modificarla hasta que yo termine de hacerlo.
¿Es esto posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con git *pelado*? **No**. La premisa *fundamental* de los sistemas distribuidos es que todos tienen sus repos y son sus dueños y señores..... digamos, en mi repositorio solo va a entrar *lo que yo quiera*. Si hay algo que no me gusta, no lo halo. Asi que no tiene sentido tener una forma de bloquear un archivo. Si alguien clona mi repositorio, son dueños y señores de hacer lo que quieran en ese archivo. De pronto tienes que mirar el flujo de trabajo del **gatekeeper**.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows

https://gist.github.com/twolfson/4564232

La presentación de linus en google explicando git habla del tema. Es vieja, pero los conceptos siguen aplicando: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8

Comment: Sí, pero mi duda es que si yo estoy modificando una clase y justo otra persona que está modificando el mismo proyecto que yo, modifica esa misma clase entonces al insertar los cambios el repo entra en conflicto... no sé si me explico

Comment: Si trabajaron sobre las mismas secciones de código, al mezclar es bastante probable que se genere un conflicto (hay ocasiones en las que no se genera un conflicto pero las condiciones no son frecuentes: ambas ramas hacen exactamente el mismo cambio. En ese caso git toma el cambio y no genera un conflicto)... si trabajaron sobre partes diferentes del mismo archivo, git mezclaría sin problemas.